# How do I sort text using table to sheet, a sheetjs library function?

Tags: javascript, excel, sheetjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzVJZ.png)
i want align text in excel

but my code is not working

please teach me solve problem tanks

```
      
let workSheet = this.$xlsx.utils.table_to_sheet(document.getElementById('qat0120MainGrid')) //input my data
      const workBook = this.$xlsx.utils.book_new() // create new sheet
      workSheet['!cols'] = [
        {
          width: 30
        },
        { width: 30 },
        { width: 30 }
      ]
      workSheet['A3'].s = { // this code is wrong?? 
        alignment: {
          horizontal: 'center'
        }
      }
      this.$xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheet, 'sheet1') // input sheetname,data
      this.$xlsx.writeFile(workBook, 'excel.xlsx') //create excel file
```

Comment: please describe how the code is not working/ what it does  now.

Comment: sorry, add picture after work code